# how to arrive at first-order correlation function with the above master equation?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, open-quantum-systems

My question arose when I was reading a paper called " Multi-photon Blockade of the dressing of the dressed states'.

This is the states this paper used:

[image]
This is the master equation this paper has arrived at:

[image]

Now I am very confused of how to arrive at the first-order correlation function, please help me! Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the quantum regression theorem?

Comment: not really, actually I was told that the correlation functions are calculated as a function of the quantum regression theorem, but I really can't figure out the specific procedure. Could you tell me what is the specific expression of the density matrix(time-dependent) of this system?

Comment: The density matrix is actually not that helpful if you want a two-time correlation function. You need to use the quantum regression theorem. I will try to write an answer later when I have time.

Comment: I have been deriving this paper for like a month and have gotten stuck in the correlation function part for half a month.But I really want to finish what I have started to do.I guess you must be as smart as Sheldon Cooper or somebody like that, so please help me when you have time. The paper is called 'Multi-photon Blockade and Dressing of the Dressed States'. Thanks a million!

Comment: It would help if you write down explicitly the correlation function you are interested in. I'm hardly an expert on this system but I do understand the quantum regression theorem, which presumably solves your problem after a tedious calculation. You can find information on this technique in Gardiner & Zoller or Breuer & Petruccione, if you have access to those texts.

Comment: I don't have access to those books, but I will try to buy them...Thank you very much!